# Runtime error using assetic w/ Symfony 2 on shared hosting

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I'm on ICDSoft hosting, so my directory structure looks like:

```
/
    private/
        app/
        bin/
        src/
        vendor/

    www/
        www/
            bundles/
            app.php
```

When I try running `$ app/console assetic:dump` I get the following runtime error:

```
[RuntimeException]
The source file "/home/thesewingdiva/private/app/../web/bundles/majorproductionssewingdivasite/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" does not exist.
```

Is there a way for me to tell assetic to look in `../www/www/bundles` rather than `../web/bundles` for the correct assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `app/config/config.yml`, in the **assetic** part :

```
assetic:
    ...
    read_from: "%kernel.root_dir%/../www/www"
    ...
```

AsseticBundle configuration documentaion for Symfony2 is here : http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/assetic.html

Comment: Well, that solved part of it, although it's still telling me that my jquery file doesn't exist, even though I'm looking at it in the right location

Comment: No, but looking more closely at the path given by the error did.  Forgot to go up another level (`../`) because I thought the context was `/private/app` not `/private/app/config`