# Symfony2 Assetic generating dead links in dev

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I'll try to keep it short, don't  want to waste your time. Working in dev environment:

template:

```
{% block javascripts %}
   {% javascripts '@SomeBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
   {% endjavascripts %}

{% endblock %}
```

html output:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/98b0881_part_1_fill_form.jquery_1.js"></script>                            
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/98b0881_part_1_jquery-1.8.3.min_2.js"></script>
```

so it reads the contents of Resources/public/js dir and makes the correct number of links with the right names. When I click  the given url however, i get 404 apache response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
        <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL /js/98b0881_part_1_jquery-1.8.3.min_2.js was not found on this server.</p>
    <hr>
    <address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at ipardon.loc Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Which pretty much means no JS for me on my page.
What have i tried:

```
app/console assets:install web --no-dev
app/console assetic:dump --no-dev
```

adding bundle name in config.yml to assetic.bundles[]
googling ( of course )

Anyone encountered anything like this before? I have, and "solved" it by not using assetic, but I'd like to get it right this time. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try app/console assetic:dump ?

Comment: okay so i cleared the cache, changed assetic.use_controller to true in config.yml ( was false, but true in config_dev.yml ) and tried assetic:dump again. it made an output of files in my web dir. does this mean i'll have to call it after every change in my js files? wth? what's with that super ultra cool "assetic will dynamically generate everything" stuff? i'd really find it usefull, but it won't be workable like this!

Comment: use assetic:dump --watch

Comment: well... i can work with that, thank you, but am a bit dissapointed. controller generating js links or whatever sounded cool :)

Comment: synx could you write the dump --watch  comment as an answer so i can accept it? thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment) you can use

```
php app/console assetic:dump --watch
```

it will automatic dump your assets if they are changed.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10913522/1570731) post hast also infos on that subject

Comment: This command remembered me that I use non standard public root. With use of http://stackoverflow.com/a/14219582/1203805 I'v corrected it and evrthg works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

In production you really only need to dump once per deployment, which can be automated (see Capifony).

In development don't use `--no-dev` parameters, this makes assetic dump compiled files only, ignoring the partial `/js/98b0881_part_1_jquery-1.8.3.min_2.js`